# How do I solve the "is not a path to a .klc file" error in Windows PowerShell when running a klc to tfl file converter script?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-type, custom-keyboard

My goal is to convert a Microsoft keyboard layout file (a .klc file) into a .tfl file that I can import into type-fu.com because I'm using a custom keyboard layout that's not listed as one of the keyboard layout options on type-fu.com.

Here is the link to the GitHub repository for the [Type-Fu-Layout-Format-Converter's code](https://github.com/LennartCode/Type-Fu-Layout-Format-Converter/blob/main/klctotfl.ps1). I don't know if the script works, but it would be helpful if someone looked at the code and checked if the script actually works.

I opened PowerShell in Windows 11, then I typed in "**powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\klctotfl.ps1**" to execute a ps1 script.

I initially got an error when I tried to use the cd. command to execute the script directly on PowerShell. The error said that scripts are disabled on PowerShell.

Then it asked for the KLC file path: "**klcFilePath:**". I typed in what I thought is the KLF file path, and I didn't receive an error from PowerShell: "**C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Organization Folders\carpalx-msklc-0.11\MSKLC\qfmlwy\qfmlwy.klc**".

Then it asked for the TFL file path and I thought I should type in what I think the name of the output's file path would be: "**C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Organization Folders\carpalx-msklc-0.11\MSKLC\qfmlwy\qfmlwy.tfl**"

I received the following error: *'' is not a path to a .klc file!
At C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\klctotfl.ps1:23 char:5

- ```
  throw "'$klcFile' is not a path to a .klc file!"
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: ('' is not a path to a .klc file!:String) [], RuntimeEx
    ception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : '' is not a path to a .klc file!*

When I typed in what I thought would be the file path of the output folder of the TFL file, I got the same error. This is what I typed: "**C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Organization Folders\carpalx-msklc-0.11\MSKLC\qfmlwy**"

How do I solve this error to make sure the KLC to TFL file converter script works?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, but try passing the arguments on the command line (all on one line): `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\klctotfl.ps1 C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Organization Folders\carpalx-msklc-0.11\MSKLC\qfmlwy\qfmlwy.klc C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Organization Folders\carpalx-msklc-0.11\MSKLC\qfmlwy\qfmlwy.tfl`. Note that the [script](https://github.com/LennartCode/Type-Fu-Layout-Format-Converter/blob/main/klctotfl.ps1) doesn't actually verify the existence of these file paths, due to (mistakenly) using `Test-Path`'s `-IsValid` switch.

Comment: Are you sure this script is known to work?  As well as @mklement0’s observation about ```Test-Path```, it also defines a script parameter ```$klcFilePath``` but then proceeds to reference a variable ```$klcFile``` in the script body, which I think is the root cause of the error…

Comment: @mclayton I don't know if the script is known to work. I've a put a link to the script's GitHub code in my question so anyone can look at the code to determine if the script should work. I don't know how to check if the script is known to work.

Comment: Excellent catch, @mclayton. Jude: Replace all instances of `$klcFile` with `$klcFilePath` and remove all uses of `-IsValid` - this should at least fix the _immediate_ problem - there may be more. I suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/LennartCode/Type-Fu-Layout-Format-Converter/issues to alert the author to these problems.